# get value from json object and return to format data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm working on my first JSON project and I have no idea how to return JSON as desired format, especially on this case. I have the following JSON :

```
function AreaToJSON() {
    var d = [];
    $.each(selectedArea, function (index, value) {
        d.push({ AreaID: value.AreaID });
    });
    return d;
}
```

and those JSON return data like this

```
[Object {AreaID : "1.3.1"}, Object{AreaID : "1.3.11"}, Object{AreaID : "1.12.4"}]
```

I need the return value like this :

```
["1.3.1", "1.3.11", "1.12.4"]
```

any suggestion about my case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just push the `value.AreaID`

```
$.each(selectedArea, function (index, value) {
    d.push(value.AreaID); // now it is an array of strings
});
```

Also if you want it as JSON, use `JSON.stringify` and to parse a JSON string, use `JSON.parse`

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are wanting an array returned

```
function AreaToJSON() {
  var d = [];
  $.each(selectedArea, function (index, value) {
    d.push(value.AreaID);
  });
  return d;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` function:

```
function areaToJson() {
  return selectedArea.map(function(area) {
    return area.AreaID;
  });
}
```